# Finding the popular (frequent) number in Tcl

Tags: tcl

It is pretty much to look for the "mode", which is the value that appears most frequently in a data set.

Here is my test code in TCL:

```
proc mode {list} {
    foreach val $list {dict incr h $val}
    set h [lsort -stride 2 -real -index 1 -decreasing $h]
    return [lindex $h 0]
}

set a [list 0 0 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.35 0.29 0.19 0.15 0.45 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39]

set m [mode $a]
puts $m
```

Is it a good/efficient way for a large dataset?
How to remove those "0" elements before the mode calculation?

Comment: This seems fine to me.      To remove "0" elements, then remove that key/value pair from the dict:  `dict unset h 0` immediately after the foreach loop.

Comment: Your dict values are integers (counts of occurrences), so why do you use the -real option to `lsort` instead of -integer?

Comment: The only tricky bit with the mode is handling when you have multiple values with the same (max) frequency; your code is fine providing "pick random member with that frequency" is a satisfactory answer (and would need a bit more work for "return list of all modal elements"). Apart from that, the code you've presented is pretty close to how I'd do it (modulo @SchelteBron's comment).

Comment: Size of the problem set is only but one factor, see my additional answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good/ efficient way for a large dataset?

Define "large" and measure!

As pointed out to you by others, your combo of `dict incr`/ `lsort -integer` is a solid choice *iff* length was the only factor:

```
Length | Method 1 | Method 2 | Ratio (m1 / m2)
-------+----------+----------+----------------
    46 |      4.4 |      7.9 |      0.55
    92 |      7.2 |     14.6 |      0.49
   184 |     12.7 |     28.2 |      0.45
   368 |     23.8 |     55.1 |      0.43
   736 |     46.2 |    108.5 |      0.43
  1472 |     90.6 |    217.3 |      0.42
  2944 |    180.2 |    428.3 |      0.42
  5888 |    359.8 |    857.4 |      0.42
 11776 |    715.9 |   1704.9 |      0.42
 23552 |   1437.0 |   3408.9 |      0.42
 47104 |   2878.2 |   6855.4 |      0.42
 94208 |   5741.7 |  13664.4 |      0.42
```

Method 1:

```
proc mode {list} {
    set h [dict create]
    foreach val $list {dict incr h $val}
    set h [lsort -stride 2 -integer -index 1 -decreasing $h]
    return [lindex $h 0]
}
```

Method 2:

```
proc mode2 {list} {
  set maxCount 0
  set mode ""
  foreach val $list {
    dict incr h $val
    set count [dict get $h $val]
    if {$count > $maxCount} {
      set maxCount $count
      set mode $val
    }
  }
  return $mode
}
```

You mentioned "real" numbers. In many cases, the distribution of levels/ bins (unique values) in a collection is even more important. Let's take the worst case that each measurement point is unique, so the length equals the number of levels/ bins:

```
 Length | Method 1 | Method 2 | Ratio (m1 / m2)
 -------+----------+----------+----------------
     23 |      4.3 |      4.8 |      0.90
     46 |      7.7 |      8.9 |      0.86
     92 |     15.6 |     17.1 |      0.91
    184 |     31.0 |     34.3 |      0.90
    368 |     63.7 |     67.9 |      0.94
    736 |    133.2 |    137.8 |      0.97
   1472 |    300.8 |    300.8 |      1.00
   2944 |    651.5 |    628.0 |      1.04
   5888 |   1560.8 |   1310.8 |      1.19
  11776 |   2886.6 |   2702.7 |      1.07
  23552 |   6408.2 |   5654.6 |      1.13
  47104 |  23331.4 |  19110.5 |      1.22
  94208 |  69697.9 |  55569.2 |      1.25
```

... then `lsort` will start becoming overly heavy on your bill. Also, if you want to detect more than one mode (bimodal etc.), then the picture changes. In either case, Method 2 above might become a valid candidate for large and heterogeneous data sets (w/ and w/o multi modes).

---

This is the driver code for the above measurement tables:

```
namespace import tcl::unsupported::timerate
timerate -calibrate {}

proc r {} {expr {10+rand()*40}}

puts " Length | Method 1 | Method 2 | Ratio (m1 / m2)"
puts " -------+----------+----------+----------------"
set l 23
while {$l <= 100000} {
    set a [list]
    for {set i 0} {$i<$l} {incr i} { lappend a [r]}
    set m1 [lindex [timerate {mode $a} 1000] 0]
    set m2 [lindex [timerate {mode2 $a} 1000] 0]
    set ratio [expr {double($m1) / double($m2)}]
    puts [format " %6d | %8.1f | %8.1f | %9.2f" $l $m1 $m2 $ratio]
    incr l $l
}

puts " Length | Method 1 | Method 2 | Ratio (m1 / m2)"
puts " -------+----------+----------+----------------"
set a [list 0 0 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.35 0.29 0.19 0.15 0.45 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39 0.39]
while {[llength $a]*2 <= 100000} {
    lappend a {*}$a
    set m1 [lindex [timerate {mode $a} 1000] 0]
    set m2 [lindex [timerate {mode2 $a} 1000] 0]
    set ratio [expr {double($m1) / double($m2)}]
    puts [format " %6d | %8.1f | %8.1f | %9.2f" [llength $a] $m1 $m2 $ratio]
}
```